# Size of wchar_t must be large enough to hold the largest character set supported by the implementation's locale

Tags: c++, char

In the book "The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition" by Stroustrup, it's mentioned that the size of `wchar_t` is implementation-defined and large enough to hold the largest character set supported by the implementation's locale.

What does this mean?

Comment: It simply means that `wchar_t` should be big enough to hold all possible wide-character constants on the target system. For example on Windows which uses UTF-16 then that means `wchar_t` must be at least 16 bits wide (but it's allowed to be wider).

Comment: This is a way to say that on Windows wchar_t is 2 bytes while on Linux it is 4.

Comment: Which bit confuses you? Do you understand what a character set is and what common ones an implementation might support?

Comment: @Some What does "locale" here refers to?

Comment: "Locale settings" is a fancier way of saying "regional settings". :) A "locale" contains information about the region, date/time formats, decimal pointer or comma, etc.

Comment: @Some Isn't this kind of locale settings defined by the implementation? Why does it have anything to do with the operating system?

Comment: @TYeung an implementation of C++ is generally a program, which needs an OS to run on. An implementation of C++ that is a compiler can also have a different target OS that the output program will run on

Comment: While you can change the locale of your program, independently of the OS, it will start out with defaults defined by the OS. Also, you can change only *parts* of the locale, like decimal point-comma, or date-time format, etc. The unchanged settings will keep the defaults by the OS.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So the locale settings are stored in the OS and the implementation of C++ will fetch that information to decide the minimum size of wchar_t, right?

Comment: Rather, the size of wchar_t is constant and big enough to support all the possible locale settings supported by a specific operating system you are compiling for. No matter if you write Mandalorian or Chinese, wchar_t can store such characters (if the operating system supports them).

Comment: Since the compiler will not know what systems the program might run in, that's not possible. Instead the compiler will use a fixed size, but a fixed size big enough to be able to run the program on any system no matter if it's a Swedish, Chinese or Arabic system (or any other country in the world).